# GUI not updating with timer or BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, user-interface, timer

I am attempting to update a GUI every second.  I have tried System.Timers.Timer, System.Windows.Forms.Timer, and BackgroundWorker.  No dice.  I'm obviously missing something.

My attempt with BackgroundWorker:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<int> counts = new List<int>() { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    List<long> complete = new List<long>() { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        backgroundWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(UpdateGUI);
        backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

        // Do stuff that updates counts and complete

        backgroundWorker.CancelAsync();
    }

    private void UpdateGUI(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var backgroundWorker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        while (backgroundWorker.CancellationPending == false)
        {

            label1.Text = count.ToString();
            labelF1.Text = counts[0].ToString();
            labelF2.Text = counts[1].ToString();
            labelF3.Text = counts[2].ToString();
            labelF4.Text = counts[3].ToString();
            labelF5.Text = counts[4].ToString();
            labelF6.Text = counts[5].ToString();
            labelF7.Text = counts[6].ToString();
            labelF8.Text = counts[7].ToString();


            labelC1.Text = complete[0].ToString();
            labelC2.Text = complete[1].ToString();
            labelC3.Text = complete[2].ToString();
            labelC4.Text = complete[3].ToString();
            labelC5.Text = complete[4].ToString();
            labelC6.Text = complete[5].ToString();
            labelC7.Text = complete[6].ToString();
            labelC8.Text = complete[7].ToString();

            Application.DoEvents();

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you getting any exception

Comment: `backgroundWorker.CancelAsync();` looks like a strong candidate for causing failure. Also, that your data never changes might also be problematic. You're also reading and writing shared state without any thought to locking. At the end of the day "not updating" is a very poor description of your problem, so anything stated here can only be a guess. I'd stick with System.Windows.Forms.Timer as these callbacks are guaranteed to occur on the UI thread. `Application.DoEvents` is *guaranteed* to not be necessary for all apps. If you need to call it, it's because you've already gone wrong.

Comment: @spender When I call UpDateGUI() within the "Do stuff that updates counts and complete" section, all is well.

Comment: @rajeev no exception, just no display (not even the first time to display the zeros).

Comment: Do your stuff in   backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted +=  backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted event

Comment: Suggest that you post the code for your attempt to use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` as this will be easiest to fix, and is likely to be the most correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
List<int> counts = new List<int>() { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
List<long> complete = new List<long>() { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };


private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    backgroundWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(UpdateGUI);
    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted 
    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

    // Do stuff that updates counts and complete

    //backgroundWorker.CancelAsync();
}

private void UpdateGUI(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        Thread.Sleep(1000);

}
private void backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
   var backgroundWorker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

        label1.Text = count.ToString();
        labelF1.Text = counts[0].ToString();
        labelF2.Text = counts[1].ToString();
        labelF3.Text = counts[2].ToString();
        labelF4.Text = counts[3].ToString();
        labelF5.Text = counts[4].ToString();
        labelF6.Text = counts[5].ToString();
        labelF7.Text = counts[6].ToString();
        labelF8.Text = counts[7].ToString();


        labelC1.Text = complete[0].ToString();
        labelC2.Text = complete[1].ToString();
        labelC3.Text = complete[2].ToString();
        labelC4.Text = complete[3].ToString();
        labelC5.Text = complete[4].ToString();
        labelC6.Text = complete[5].ToString();
        labelC7.Text = complete[6].ToString();
        labelC8.Text = complete[7].ToString();

        Application.DoEvents();

   }
 }
```