# Graph dynamic update

Tags: c#

I have an application that acquires temperature data from the serial port every time that the temperature changes. The value get stored in a variable and is shown in a text box.
I would like to show the temperature versus time in a graph.
I have setup the graph as following but I don't know where to start to get the temperature line updated versus time every second.

```
 InitializeComponent();
        //Chart
        chart1.ChartAreas.Add("areas");
        chart1.ChartAreas["areas"].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
        chart1.ChartAreas["areas"].AxisX.Interval = 1;
        chart1.ChartAreas["areas"].AxisY.Minimum = 0;
        chart1.ChartAreas["areas"].AxisY.Maximum = 250;
        chart1.ChartAreas["areas"].AxisY.Interval = 10;
        chart1.ChartAreas["areas"].AxisX.Title = "Time [s]";
        chart1.ChartAreas["areas"].AxisY.Title = "Temperature [°C]";
        chart1.Series.Add("Temperature");
        chart1.Series["Temperature"].Color = Color.Red;
        chart1.Series["Temperature"].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
        chart1.Titles.Add("Extruder Temperature");

       //this two lines are only to see something in the graph
        chart1.Series["Temperature"].Points.AddXY(0, 20);
        chart1.Series["Temperature"].Points.AddXY(1, 50);
    }
```

I think I need to update the "point" and the "value" (0, 20) by replacing the values with the variables but if I do so, I have only one point in the graph and I cannot show the previous values. 
Being a beginner I would appreciate some help.

Comment: are you using Windows Forms or WPF?

Comment: @jle I am using windows Forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you acquired new data, simply add another Datapoint:
Just to give you an idea (as you haven't posted your data receive method):

```
OnSerialReceive()
{
    var temp = serialport.read();
    var time = (int)stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
    chart1.Series["Temperature"].Points.AddXY(time, temp);
}
```

And yes, as soon as you get real data into your diagram, you will want to remove your fake data. Fake data is confusing.

Comment: I think he will also need to remove the first `Datapoint` so that graph does not `ZoomOut` and so that will seem as running graph as seen in Windows Task Manager for RAM usage..

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am taking the direction you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way (to refresh every second) is to use a BackgroundWorker.  This question give an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15548009/gui-not-updating-with-timer-or-backgroundworker).  Essentially, you start a background thread that updates the view every set amount of time.

```
private BackgroundWorker _bw;

....
    InitializeComponent();
    _bw = new BackgroundWorker
    {
      WorkerReportsProgress = true,
      WorkerSupportsCancellation = true
    };
    _bw.DoWork += bw_DoWork;
    _bw.ProgressChanged += bw_ProgressChanged;
    _bw.RunWorkerCompleted += bw_RunWorkerCompleted;

    _bw.RunWorkerAsync ("Hello to worker");
     if (_bw.IsBusy) _bw.CancelAsync();
  }

  private void bw_DoWork (object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
  {

      if (_bw.CancellationPending) { e.Cancel = true; return; }
      var dataPoints = YourConnectToSerialPortAndGetDataFunction();
      _bw.ReportProgress (dataPoints);
      Thread.Sleep (1000); 

    e.Result = dataPoints;    // This gets passed to RunWorkerCompleted
  }

  private void bw_RunWorkerCompleted (object sender,
                                     RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
  {

}

  private void bw_ProgressChanged (object sender,
                                  ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
  {
//UPDATE YOUR LABEL
chart1.Series["Temperature"].Points.AddXY(0, 20);
        chart1.Series["Temperature"].Points.AddXY(1, 50);
  }
```